# How to write unit test using jasmine to cover DOM in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dom, jasmine, karma-runner

Im facing an issue on writing the unit tests for one of the controller in angular JS. Im using Karma jasmine 2.8.0.

Controller code :-

```
var checkedlength = angular.element(e.target).parents('checkbox').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;});

if(checkedlength === 0){/* code here */} 
else {/* code here */}
```

Where `e` is the event.

I wanted to write unit test using jasmine so that both if and else part can be covered.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the question is clear enough. First of all what do you want to test? Which cases should be covered.
Second the code example is very short and does not contain angular specific code except for angular.element which is in essence just a dom lookup. 
And third angularjs discourages dom manipulation in controllers. You should use a directive for dom manipulation. 
But I'm not sure what you are trying to do. As I said not enough information/code

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: We have written a code that would do the operation based on the number of checkboxes. Based on the length the logic is written. For this, DOM manipulation is done in the controller file. Code was written in such a way that the DOM manipulaiton is done in the controller itself using the angular.element. We understand that this is not as per the standard but this was missed somehow intially  and the client forces on the 90% unit test coverage for the deployment to happen. So, we are trying to write unit test cases and unable to cover these lines and we are struck here.

Comment: We are unable to set the value for the angular.element(e.target).parents().find().length from the jasmine file so that both the if and else can be covered. Please let me know if i still needs to be more clearer on the question.

Comment: This should feasible if you mock the angular.element call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mock the angular.element call. Something like this. It is not complete but should get you started.

```
var arrayOfCheckboxes = ['checbox1', 'checkbox2'];
var angularSpy;
var elementFunction = function(e){ return anyMockedElement; }
var domCheckBoxes = {
   find: function(searchString){
      if(string === 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked'){
           return arrayOfCheckboxes;
      }
   }
}
var anyMockedElement = {
    parents: function(string) {
        if(string === 'checkbox'){
           return domCheckBoxes;
        }
    }
}

beforeEach(function() {
    angularSpy = spyOn(angular, 'element').andCallFake(elementFunction);   
});

afterEach(function() {
    angularSpy.andCallThrough();
});
```

Comment: Thanks David. It worked well when we tried the same way you have suggested but with slight modifications.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept my answer/ or provide your answer?